# Understanding MATLAB/Ocatave file reading

Tags: matlab, octave, filereader

The following is a dedicated function to read [MNIST data files](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

```
function [tlab, tvec] = readmnist(datafn, labelfn)
% function reads mnist data and labels 

fid = fopen(datafn, 'rb');
//open datafn in read and big-endian format.
//returns a file-id
if fid==-1
   error('Error opening data file');
end;

fseek(fid, 0, 'eof');
// Seek to the 0th byte from the end of the file.
// In other words. Just go to the end of the file.
// fid == the file to be accessed.
// 'eof' == relative position.
// 0 == bytes to be read.

cnt = (ftell(fid) - 16)/784;

fseek(fid, 16, 'bof');
//Move to the 16th byte from the beginning of file.
tvec = zeros(cnt, 784);
//returns a 2D cntx784 matrix of zeros.

for i=1:cnt
   im = fread(fid, 784, 'uchar');
   tvec(i,:) = (im(:)/255.0)';
end;
fclose(fid);
cnt

fid = fopen(labelfn, 'rb');
if fid==-1
   error('Error opening label file');
end;
fseek(fid, 8, 'bof');
[tlab nel] = fread(fid, cnt, 'uchar');
if nel ~= cnt 
   disp('Not all elements read.');
end;
fclose(fid);
nel
```

Could you tell me what is the catch with the following line?

```
cnt = (ftell(fid) - 16)/784;
```

What is going on here? What is 784?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the code, `tvec` (the data being read in from the file), is known to be `cnt x 784` and `cnt` is unknown. The line that you have pasted, solves for `cnt`.

Since the previous line causes the file pointer to point to the end of the file, `ftell(fid)` will tell the current position in the file which in this case corresponds to the total number of bytes in the file. They then subtract 16 because apparently the first 16 bytes are not part of the data of interest. Now, we know that `cnt * 784 = ftell(fid) - 16` so to solve for `cnt` we just need to divide by `784`.

The following lines then move the file pointer back to the 17-th byte (the beginning of the data) and then loop through `1:cnt` to then read in each 784-byte piece with `fread`.